# What happens if I multiply a point by a scaling matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, linear-transformations

If I multiply a point by a translation matrix the point is translated. If I multiply a point by a rotation matrix the point is rotated. These two transformations are intuitive.
**But, when I multiply a point by a scaling matrix it is not scaled (it cannot be), rather it is like "transformed"!** This is counter-intuitive!
Can anyone please explain this to me? And how is scaling done on a complex 3D model with texture applied on it in computer graphics?

Comment: Well aren't scaling matrix defined with respect to a certain "fixed" point? (usually (0,0,0) )

Comment: Yes, but since I'm new to linear algebra, can you explain it more? That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I posted it as a comment to "hint" you at the correct explanation, which AOrtiz excellently gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scaling transformation $T$, as you call it has the property that for $v\in\Bbb R^3$, $Tv = \alpha v$, for some $\alpha \in\Bbb R.$ To see how this looks in matrix form, we use the fact that a linear transformation is determined on a basis, say $e_1, e_2, e_3$, the standard basis. $Te_1 = (\alpha, 0, 0)$, $Te_2 = (0,\alpha, 0)$, $Te_3 = (0,0,\alpha)$. Hence, the matrix $A$ of $T$ is:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So, if you take any point $v\in\Bbb R^3$ and compute $Av$, you will find that the result is equivalent to applying the transformation $\alpha\,\cdot\,\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ that "scales" a vector $v$ via standard scalar multiplication. In other words, $Av = \alpha \cdot v$.

Comment: That explains a lot. 
But, suppose that I have a line consisting of 1000 points and I want to scale it to make it appear larger. If I do scaling for 1000 points one by one I don't get more than 1000 points. Then how is the scaling happening?!

Comment: @ShuvoSarker, if the scaling is still of this type, then the scaling is happening in the exact same way. That is, for each of the points $v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_{1000}$, we compute $Av_1,Av_2,\ldots,Av_{1000}.$ This is the same "line," with each point on the line scaled by the appropriate transformation.

Comment: @AOritz... But how!? The number of points is the same in both cases. The second case makes the line appear larger with the same number of points just in different locations! **I cannot picture it in my mind!**

Comment: The interval $[0,1]$ contains as many points as the whole $\mathbb{R}$. Weird things can happen when infinity is involved.
Another example: natural numbers are just as many as natural even numbers. Just consider the bijection $n \to 2n$

Comment: @ShuvoSarker, If you are talking about line *segments*, then you are right, the length of the new line is $\alpha$ times longer, and they are *not* the same segment. However, if you are referring to a line defined by $1000$ points, then the transformed line is exactly the same as the untransformed line.

Comment: @AOrtiz, thanks very. You mentioned _line segment_ and _a line defined by 1000 points_. Could you please tell me which one of these concept is used in computer graphics and how?

Comment: @ShuvoSarker keep in mind it only takes two points to define a line uniquely. As far as your other question, you may have more luck asking on one of the other stackexchange sites such as stack overflow. Good luck in your search for an answer to that question and keep in mind that a segment and a line are two distinct objects and their use and applications likely depend on the application you are searching for.